# Debugging parameters

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a query which has an `OUTER APPLY` to a table-valued function that takes two parameters:

- The first parameter is a declared variable [`@Country`]
- The second parameter is a variable set from a table value which can change from line to line [`a.Weekending_date`]

For some reason the report goes wrong half way through due to this `OUTER APPLY` so I am trying to find out what is being passed to this table-valued function.

Normally I'd use `Print` but you can print a table value and debug will not run.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "report goes wrong half way through "?

Comment: The report produces nulls about half way through and I needed to know what value was being passed to the TVF.
I have now resolved the report but would still value how to debug the value being passed to the TVF if anyone can help.